# Do images in plugins automatically load?

Tags: plugins, images

I have a plugin that I've written that simply provides functionality for shortcodes for images in the plugins /includes/svg folder.  So essentially a page can use a short code tag to place an image in an HTML block.

My image folder is getting really big, and I don't want the user to have to download all of my images just to see one page.

My question is: will a browser download all of the images in the /include/svg directory if the plugin affects the page, or does Wordpress only provide those images if the shortcode specifically calls for the image?

I suppose I could clear my browser cache just to find out, but I like my cache.

Comment: If you display all the images on the same page, then yes, the browser would load them all, so limit the number of images displayed per page and I'd also show just thumbnails that link to the full image.

Comment: Thanks Sally. I can't upvote comments but you really helped me .

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't. There's zero reason a browser would just download images from the server if they're not used on the page. If that were a thing that could happen then all your uploaded files would download, and obviously that doesn't happen.